# Does Shadow of Moil grant the user advantage against enemies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, warlock, vision-and-light

Shadow of Moil strikes me as the Warlock's equivalent of Greater Invisibility, with a few perks. One major point of contention among my party, however, is whether or not it grants the user advantage against enemies that see it.

While Greater Invisibility grants advantage by attacking unseen, Shadow of Moil grants the user the heavily obscured condition, which renders all enemies viewing the target as effectively blinded. Attacking enemies with the blinded condition imposes advantage.

However, The Player's Handbook Errata clarifies:

> A heavily obscured area doesn’t blind you, but you are effectively blinded when you try to see something obscured by it.

How am l supposed to treat Shadow of Moil's effects, RAW?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does. If you cast Shadow of Moil on yourself, you are in a heavily obscured area, so enemies are "effectively blinded" when they try to see or attack you while the spell is active. As such, you are treated as an unseen attacker (or an unseen target), and correspondingly get advantage on attacks against enemies (and enemies get disadvantage on attacks against you).

This should work even on creatures with darkvision, since the spell unequivocally states that you become heavily obscured to others. That said, this is a bit unclear since the next sentence states "The shadows turn dim light within 10 feet of you into darkness, and bright light in the same area to dim light." - which implies that the reason it's obscured is a magical darkness.

The reason for the clarification in the PHB errata is that in a heavily obscured area (e.g. darkness), you are effectively blinded when it comes to seeing other creatures that are also heavily obscured - but the designers wanted to clarify that you could still see other things that are in lit areas even when you yourself are in darkness.